# How to open a specific page for a react app

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a issue with opening a specific page for a react app. There is a home page and a new home re-design page and whenever I run Npm start it always opens the original home page instead of the new home re-design page. I attached a screenshot of my vscode for the specific page I want to open [underlined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqMKe.png) in green. Thank you!

I tried everything including deleting the original home page but my fixes are ineffective at getting the home re-design page to open.

Comment: React doesn't have pages natively. It depends on your router implementation. Which one are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.